# How to debug a child process which is already under debug

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, sandbox

I have two process (Linux ELF): process A is a main process and B is a child process (A uses fork() to create B). A also uses ptrace to trace the B (like some kind of sandbox) catching the B’s `int 3` instruction.

I want to use GDB to debug process B. When I tried GDB to attach the child process B, it shows an error that B is already under debug. So do I have a way to debug the child process which is already under another “debugger”?

In my case, A and B have interactions, I cannot directly patch or rewrite the code in A to disable ptrace function.

Answer (score 0):

> So do I have a way to debug the child process which is already under another “debugger”?

No.

Having a child that is `ptrace`'d by its parent, with non-trivial interaction between the two, is one of the few effective anti-debugging techniques.

To debug `B`, you would have to run it without `A` sandboxing it, and would have to replicate the interaction between `A` and `B` by "emulating" what process `A` normally does to process `B` through GDB.